# Why is there a lawnmower in my kitchen?

Tags: golf-story

After meeting Max Yards in Bermuda Isles and winning the long drive competition, I was surprised to find a lawnmower in the middle of my kitchen when I woke up the next morning.

Interacting with the mower doesn't do anything special. It just makes a few random engine noises without any comment from the main character.

**Why is there a lawnmower in my kitchen? Does it serve any purpose?**

[image: lawnmower in kitchen]

Comment: this is one of those unintentionally hilarious questions when you don't know the context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The lawnmower is a reward for getting a hole-in-one on the Bermuda Isles Aqua Golf range.**

At the Aqua Golf driving range in Bermuda Isles, there is a small putting green surrounded by water about 160 yards out on a dock. Behind the green is a brick wall with a target you can bounce shots off of.

[image: Aqua Golf putting green]

If you manage to sink your ball in the hole with a single shot, a man in the ticket booth will tell you to talk to him for a prize. As you could probably guess, the prize is a lawnmower shipped directly to your house.

The main character remarks that he doesn’t know where he could even keep a lawnmower in his tiny house. Apparently he decided that kitchen was the best place.

As far as I can tell, the lawnmower serves absolutely no purpose other than taking up space in your house.